# Using rxjs operator is it possible to get second last value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This is the sample code using `rxjs` operator, I want to print/get the second last value.

**typescript**

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, last } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit (1,2,3,4,5)
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//add 10 to each value
const example = source.pipe(map(val => val + 10)).pipe(last());
//output: 11,12,13,14,15
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Currently it prints `15` but I want it to print `14` instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make use of the [takeLast()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeLast) and [skipLast](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/skipLast) RxJS operator.

The `takeLast()` operator allows you to

> Emits only the last `count` values emitted by the source Observable.

while the `skipLast()` operator

> Skip the last `count` values emitted by the source Observable.

Now, we can combine both pipeable operators such that we will take the last 2 counts, and skip the last count.

```
import { range, from } from 'rxjs';
import { takeLast, map, skipLast} from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

const example = source
  .pipe(
    map(val => val + 10),
    takeLast(2), 
    skipLast(1)
  );

example.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/5qfuyt-alx3ay?file=index.ts).

Comment: Nice solution, it returns only the target value.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pairwise operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map,last } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit (1,2,3,4,5)
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//add 10 to each value
const example = source.pipe(map(val => val + 10)).pipe(pairwise(),last());
//output: 11,12,13,14,15
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

- `takeLast` take last `n` emitted values before completion
- `take` will take the first `n` number

```
import { from } from "rxjs";
import { take, takeLast } from "rxjs/operators";

const source = from([1,2,3,4,5]);

source
  .pipe(
    takeLast(2), 
    take(1) 
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```